# update multiple rows with different values python and mysql

Tags: python, mysql

i want to update multiple rows with different values.

for example my table is :

> id | Name |   Data
>
> 1  |ahmad | year 2015
>
> 2 | ali | year 2014

i want my table to look like this:

> id | Name |   Data  | number
>
> 1  |ahmad | year 2015 | 2
>
> 2 | ali | year 2014  | 3

There are more than 7000 rows i can't fill them one by one.

The query i am trying to do so in python is:

```
 #words count in a tweet
    words= processedRow.split()
    fdist2=len(words)

    for val in cursor.fetchall():
        cursor.execute("""UPDATE TWEETER1 SET t1=%s where id = %s""",(fdist2,val))
        db.commit()
```

Kindly help me in doing my work. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. 7000 is a low number for a computer.

You could try to optimise it for >100k to use multiple database connections or not to commit on each update but that's outside the scope of your questions.

Comment: can you please help me in query?